# Cannot delete a data relationship in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, relationships, data

I have set up a couple of data relationships in Salesforce Marketing cloud. I later removed the underlying data extensions and now it is not possible to remove the original data relationships. The reason that I need to remove the relationships is that we have changed the data models and configuration of the data extensions but still need the relationships.

This is the error that I receive when trying to delete the data relationship.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact to support to have them do this. It represents an instability in the platform - it's referencing a table that doesn't exist and thus it can't remove the relationship.

For future references, you would need to delete the relationship prior to deleting the data extension.

Hope this helps :-)